# How to do a complex edit of columns of all data frames in a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, integer, multiple-columns

I have a list of 185 data frames called `WaFramesNumeric`. Each dataframe has several hundred columns and thousands of rows. I want to edit every data frame, so that it leaves all numeric columns as well as any non-numeric columns that I specify.

Using:

```
for(i in seq_along(WaFramesNumeric)) {
    WaFramesNumeric[[i]] <- WaFramesNumeric[[i]][,sapply(WaFramesNumeric[[i]],is.numeric)] 
}
```

successfully makes each dataframe contain only its numeric columns.

I've tried to amend this with lines to add specific columns. I have tried:

```
for (i in seq_along(WaFramesNumeric)) {
    a <- WaFramesNumeric[[i]]$Device_Name
    WaFramesNumeric[[i]] <- WaFramesNumeric[[i]][,sapply(WaFramesNumeric[[i]],is.numeric)] 
    cbind(WaFramesNumeric[[i]],a)
}
```

and in an attempt to call the column numbers of all integer columns as well as the specific ones and then combine based on that:

```
for (i in seq_along(WaFramesNumeric)) {
    f <- which(sapply(WaFramesNumeric[[i]],is.numeric))
    m <- match("Cost_Center",colnames(WaFramesNumeric[[i]]))
    n <- match("Device_Name",colnames(WaFramesNumeric[[i]]))
    combine <- c(f,m,n)
    WaFramesNumeric[[i]][,i,combine]
}
```

These all return errors and I am stumped as to how I could do this. `WaFramesNumeric` is a copy of another list of dataframes (`WaFramesNumeric <- WaFramesAll`) and so I also tried adding the specific columns from the `WaFramesAll` but this was not successful.

I appreciate any advice you can give and I apologize if any of this is unclear.

Comment: What are you expecting with a double-comma indexing of `WaFramesNumeric[[i]][,i,combine]`? As far as I know, the position you fill with `combine` is for just `drop=` or `exact=`, not integer positions. Also, if `i` refers to a specific data.frame within the list, why are you using it within the inner data.frame indexing? I'd think it would just be `WaFramesNumeric[[i]][,combine]`.

Comment: @r2evans Truthfully I am newer to R and I've been working on this specific issue for a long time. That was when I received the error that I wasn't specifying a column. I've definitely made some errors, but I just wanted to show my thought process when asking the question. The first line that works, ideally, could have a few lines added to specify adding columns to the new frame that is only numeric columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mistakenly assuming that the last commmand in a `for` loop is meaningful. It is not. In fact, it is being discarded, so since you never assigned it anywhere (the `cbind` and the indexing of `WaFramesNumeric...`), it is silently discarded.

Additionally, you are over-indexing your data.frame in the third code block. First, it's using `i` within the data.frame, even though `i` is an index within the `list` of data.frames, not the frame itself. Second (perhaps caused by this), you are trying to index three dimensions of a 2D frame. Just change the last indexing from `[,i,combine]` to either `[,combine]` or `[combine]`.

Third problem (though perhaps not seen yet) is that `match` will return `NA` if nothing is found. Indexing a frame with an `NA` returns an error (try `mtcars[,NA]` to see). I suggest that you can replace `match` with `grep`: it returns `integer(0)` when nothing is found, which is what you want in this case.

```
for (i in seq_along(WaFramesNumeric)) {
  f <- which(sapply(WaFramesNumeric[[i]], is.numeric))
  m <- grep("Cost_Center", colnames(WaFramesNumeric[[i]]))
  n <- grep("Device_Name", colnames(WaFramesNumeric[[i]]))
  combine <- c(f,m,n)
  WaFramesNumeric[[i]] <- WaFramesNumeric[[i]][combine]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I did indeed think that everything in the loop was happening in order and did not realize that was being discarded at all. I ran this but the result is the same as my line of `for(i in seq_along(WaFramesNumeric)){
  WaFramesNumeric[[i]] <- WaFramesNumeric[[i]][,sapply(WaFramesNumeric[[i]],is.numeric)] 
}` . So does that mean it is ignoring the part where I want those two, non-numeric columns of `"Cost_Center"` and `Device_Name"` included?

Comment: EDIT: I tried a different avenue, but `grep`  and your example was integral so, again, thanks a lot! It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "an attempt to call the column numbers of all integer columns...", but in case you want to go through a list of data frames and select some columns based on some function and keep given a column name you can do like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(20), b=rnorm(20), c=letters[1:20], d=letters[1:20], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
WaFramesNumeric <- rep(list(df), 2)

Selector <- function(data, select_func, select_names) {
  select_func <- match.fun(select_func)
  idx_names <- match(select_names, colnames(data))
  idx_names <- idx_names[!is.na(idx_names)]
  idx_func <- which(sapply(data, select_func))
  idx <- unique(c(idx_func, idx_names))
  return(data[, idx])
}

res <- lapply(X = WaFramesNumeric, FUN = Selector, select_names=c("c"), select_func = is.numeric)
```

Comment: Sorry for the being unclear. I was attempting to get around my issue by, via the loop, calling the column numbers of a data frame for any column that is numeric and for any others that I specify. Then I was to replace the frame by binding using the column numbers as reference. But thank you for this, it does help! I'll give it a try.