# R: How do you subset all data-frames within a list?

Tags: r, subset, col

I have a list of data-frames called `WaFramesCosts`. I want to simply subset it to show specific columns so that I can then export them. I have tried:

```
    for (i in names(WaFramesCosts)) {
      WaFramesCosts[[i]][,c("Cost_Center","Domestic_Anytime_Min_Used","Department",
"Domestic_Anytime_Min_Used")]

    }
```

but it returns the error of

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(WaFramesCosts[[i]], , c("Cost_Center", "Department",  : 
  undefined columns selected
```

I also tried:

```
for (i in seq_along(WaFramesCosts)){
WaFramesCosts[[i]][ , -which(names(WaFramesCosts[[i]]) %in% c("Cost_Center","Domestic_Anytime_Min_Used","Department",
    "Domestic_Anytime_Min_Used"))]
```

but I get the same error. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Side Note: For reference, I used this:

```
for (i in seq_along(WaFramesCosts)) {
    t <- WaFramesCosts[[i]][ , grepl( "Domestic" , names( WaFramesCosts[[i]] ) )] 
    q <- subset(WaFramesCosts[[i]], select = c("Cost_Center","Domestic_Anytime_Min_Used","Department","Domestic_Anytime_Min_Used"))  

    WaFramesCosts[[i]] <- merge(q,t)
  }
```

while attempting the same goal with a different approach and seemed to get closer.

Comment: please post your data or at least a reproducible example

Comment: @Parfait thank you for catching that. I have been trying to work on this for quite some time, so I accidentally copied and pasted an old naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome back, Kootseeahknee. You are [still](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48971241/3358272) incorrectly assuming that the last command of a `for` loop is implicitly returned at the end. If you want that behavior, perhaps you want `lapply`:

```
myoutput <- lapply(names(WaFramesCosts)), function(i) {
  WaFramesCosts[[i]][,c("Cost_Center","Domestic_Anytime_Min_Used","Department","Domestic_Anytime_Min_Used")]
})
```

The `undefined columns selected` error tells me that your assumptions of the datasets are not correct: at least one is missing at least one of the columns. From your previous question ([How to do a complex edit of columns of all data frames in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48971076/3358272)), I'm inferring that you want columns that match, not assuming that it is in everything. From that, you could/should be using `grep` or some variant:

```
myoutput <- lapply(names(WaFramesCosts)), function(i) {
  WaFramesCosts[[i]][,grep("(Cost_Center|Domestic_Anytime_Min_Used|Department)", 
                           colnames(WaFramesCosts)),drop=FALSE]
})
```

This will match column names that contain any of those strings. You can be a lot more precise by ensuring whole strings or start/end matches occur by using regular expressions. For instance, changing from `(Cost|Dom)` (anything that contains "Cost" or "Dom") to `(^Cost|Dom)` means anything that *starts* with "Cost" or *contains* "Dom"; similarly, `(Cost|ment$)` matches anything that contains "Cost" or *ends* with "ment". If, however, you always want exact matches and just need those that exist, then something like this will work:

```
myoutput <- lapply(names(WaFramesCosts)), function(i) {
  WaFramesCosts[[i]][,intersect(c("Cost_Center","Domestic_Anytime_Min_Used","Department"),
                                colnames(WaFramesCosts)),drop=FALSE]
})
```

Note, in that last example: notice the difference between `mtcars[,2]` (returns a vector) and `mtcars[,2,drop=FALSE]` (returns a `data.frame` with 1 column). Defensive programming, if you think it at all possible that your filtering will return a single-column, make sure you do not inadvertently convert to a `vector` by appending `,drop=FALSE` to your bracket-subsetting.

Comment: Ha, once again, I make this mistake. I should step away from the project for a bit as my head is swimming with all of these concepts. i apologize for the overnight. I posted this question as I was trying, yet again, a new approach to my goal. Thank you for the matching help, asl well; these column names are numerous, messy and not always the same so that will help find them much more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, this is an example of using library dplyr to achieve combining a list of data frames for a given set of columns. This doesn't require  all data frames to have identical columns (Providing your data in a reproducible example would be better)

```
# test data

df1 = read.table(text = "
c1 c2 c3
a 1 101
b 2 102
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 = read.table(text = "
c1 c2 c3
w 11 201
x 12 202
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# dfs is a list of data frames
dfs <- list(df1, df2)

# use dplyr::bind_rows
library(dplyr)

cols <- c("c1", "c3")
result <- bind_rows(dfs)[cols]

result

# c1  c3
# 1  a 101
# 2  b 102
# 3  w 201
# 4  x 202
```

Comment: Why import a whole package just for `bind_rows`? Base R's `do.call(rbind, dfs)` could easily work.

Comment: I agree in this small example, @Parfait. In more extensive work I tend to use dplyr anyway `bind_rows` is claimed  to be  an efficient implementation of the common pattern of do.call(rbind, dfs)" and it is more forgiving of column mismatches etc, so a little easier to use.

Comment: @epi99 I will try this, thanks! I have been trying to avoid it for several reasons, but it seems combining these in this fashion may be my only hope for the results I want.